# iphone 4s cloud backup issue

Tags: iphone, backup

I have my iphone 4s set up to backup on the cloud and i have paid for extra storage place on the cloud i plug my phone up at night and have it connected to the wifi to backup when i sleep but it doesnt work i  then get notification that my phone has not backed up in 12 weeks...what should i check i am paying for extra space and yet nothing is getting backed up. Even when i am connected to my wifi and do a backup now it doesnt back up apparently...

Answer (score 1):

My 4S wasn't backing up either. There are several things to try that might fix this. These steps worked for me.

- hard reboot
- upgrade to the latest iOS version
- toggle off iCloud Backup, then toggle it back on